# unhandled exception in thread started by ... , in cmd?

Tags: django

Please help me , where is problem here in a picture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When asking a question, please provide some context (what are you attempting to do, what have you tried so far), along with a specific question. Adding images that contain text only is not ideal, please copy and paste the text instead.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

look at the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#include
basically, the error is  quite self-explanatory if you are using namespace you have to use it with app_name  like this

`include(module, namespace=my_app, app_name=my_app)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an `app_name` attribute in the included URLconf module. Such as if your app's name is `my_awesome_app` then add it in `my_awesome_app/urls.py` file. Like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'my_awesome_app'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) for more information.